# Dynamically populating nested Perl hashes and arrays

Tags: arrays, perl, hash

I haven't yet mastered the difference between arrays and hashes, array of hashes, hashes of hashes etc. so I don't know what the code below is defining. Would someone kindly let me know which it is please?

```
my $col_props = [
    {   min_w   => 50,                                                 # Minimum column width.
        max_w   => 50,                                                 # Maximum column width.
        justify => 'left',                                             # One of left|center|right ,
        font    => $pdf->corefont( "Arial", -encoding => "latin1" ),
    },
    {   min_w   => 110,                                                # Minimum column width.
        max_w   => 110,                                                # Maximum column width.
        justify => 'left',                                             # One of left|center|right ,
        font    => $pdf->corefont( "Arial", -encoding => "latin1" ),
    },
    {   min_w   => 110,                                                # Minimum column width.
        max_w   => 110,                                                # Maximum column width.
        justify => 'left',                                             # One of left|center|right ,
        font    => $pdf->corefont( "Arial", -encoding => "latin1" ),
    },
];
```

However, my real question is, given the code above how do I populate `$col_props` dynamically?

Comment: http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html#ARRAYS-OF-HASHES

Comment: populate it from what?

Answer (score 3):

`$col_props` is a *reference* to an array of hashes.

For instance, the maximum column width for the second entry is

```
$col_props->[1]{max_w}
```

How you populate it depends what you want to do. Suppose you have a column definition in `%column_data` then you can push it (add it to the end) of the array using

```
push @$col_props, \%column_data
```

to modify or add a field of one of the hashes simply assign to it, for instance

```
$col_props->[2]{min_w} = 20
```

Answer (score 0):

`$col_props` is an array of hashes.

The `$` and the `[ ]` in the assignment suggest that `$col_props` is an array reference.

One method could be this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w


my $col_props = [
    {   min_w   => 50,                          # Minimum column width.
        max_w   => 50,                          # Maximum column width.
        justify => 'left'                     # One of left|center|right ,
    },
    {   min_w   => 110,                           # Minimum column width.
        max_w   => 110,                          # Maximum column width.
        justify => 'left'                       # One of left|center|right ,
    },
    {   min_w   => 110,                             # Minimum column width.
        max_w   => 110,                            # Maximum column width.
        justify => 'left'                           # One of left|center|right ,
    },
];

foreach my $ref (@{$col_props}) { #1 print
  print "min_w: ". $ref->{min_w} . "\n"
  . "max_w: " . $ref->{max_w} . "\n";
}

my %new_hash = ( # create a new hash to push
  min_w => 1,
  max_w => 2,
  justify => 'right'
);


push @{$col_props}, \%new_hash; # pushing the new_hash reference
print "\n";

foreach my $ref (@{$col_props}) { #2 print
  print "min_w: ". $ref->{min_w} . "\n"
  . "max_w: " . $ref->{max_w} . "\n";
}
```

`#1 print:`

```
min_w: 50
max_w: 50
min_w: 110
max_w: 110
min_w: 110
max_w: 110
```

`#2 print:`

```
min_w: 50
max_w: 50
min_w: 110
max_w: 110
min_w: 110
max_w: 110
min_w: 1
max_w: 2
```

To better understand, have a look [here](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html).